# "message": "Request failed with status code 400"

Tags: axios, graphql, nestjs

[image]
{
"errors": [
{
"message": "Request failed with status code 400",
"locations": [
{
"line": 2,
"column": 3
}
],
"path": [
"launch"
],
"extensions": {
"code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
"exception": {
"config": {
"url": "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/3",
"method": "get",
"headers": {
"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
"User-Agent": "axios/0.21.1",
"host": "api.spacexdata.com",
"Proxy-Authorization": "Basic YTcxMDMwODpOb3J0aHdlc3QyMDIy"
},
"transformRequest": [
null
],
"transformResponse": [
null
],
"timeout": 0,
"xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
"xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
"maxContentLength": -1,
"maxBodyLength": -1
}
}
}
}
],
"data": {
"launch": null
}
}

I am receiving this error and not able to find why its coming as the url working fine in the postman or in browser.

my query looks like

{
launches{
site,
id
}
}

this the query i am doing in the playground of graphql

Comment: Can you show the service code? Making a `GET` request to the url works fine, so there's probably something else happening. Do you see any error information in your terminal?

Comment: Error in the terminal:Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/Users/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)

Comment: Can you show the service code that's making the HTTP call? Strange that it just says 400

Comment: Attached the image of Service file